# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/ParameterBindings

Tags: grails, jms

I am seeing this error after the server run for more than one day. There is no error when server starts.

```
org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'onMessage' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/ParameterBindings
        at grails.plugin.jms.listener.adapter.PersistenceContextAwareListenerAdapter.invokeListenerMethod(PersistenceContextAwareListenerAdapter.groovy:44)
        at grails.plugin.jms.listener.adapter.LoggingListenerAdapter.onMessage(LoggingListenerAdapter.groovy:48)
        at grails.plugin.jms.listener.adapter.PersistenceContextAwareListenerAdapter.onMessage(PersistenceContextAwareListenerAdapter.groovy:33)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/ParameterBindings
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.clientPrepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:1450)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4165)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4069)
```

Comment: Are there any inactivity within one day? Do you see any error related to `"Broken pipe"`. Can you post your DataSource configuration?

Comment: @Aramiti : Well these are service adapter which invoke only when it's called from other application. So yes there is possibility that it become inactive for several hours unless some request invoke it.  In my DataSource.groovy , I have mapped JNDI so nothing over there.  Error related to broken pipe , I saw only once. but not anymore

Comment: I will add a DataSource setting as an answer and see if it will resolve this issue.

Comment: Figure out the issue as the deployment server lib folder missing database connection jars though it's present in war file. After copying those jars , I am not seeing these error.

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be due to database inactivity. The following setting might help you to keep the database connectivity active, in case there are none, for a long period of time:

```
timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
validationQueryTimeout = 3
validationInterval = 15000
testOnBorrow = true
autoReconnect=true
testWhileIdle = true
```

Comment: All these setting are mapped in jndi configuration